# Cмешанный контент в админке Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Добрый день подскажите в чем проблема может быть. При нажатии на некоторые пункты меню в админ панели Joomla 3.8.10 в данном случае изменить материал записи в меню появляется белый экран а в консоли написано "Mixed сontent" как понял ругается на jquery.min.js. Я еще понимаю скрипты и стили в самом шаблоне переподключить через https но что делать с админкой? На сайте стоит сертификат SSL.
[Ccылка на скрин с админки](http://SSMaker.ru/79838014/)

Comment: Если страница грузилась по https, а файлы пытаются загрузится по простому http - то браузер по умолчанию блокирует такую загрузку. Исправьте это, и все загрузится нормально

Comment: Да я понимаю. но где мне искать эти подключения? в шаблоне все нормально работает а вот в админке блочит. Грешу на джквери так как многие всплывающие окна пишет смешанный контент. Если в админке блокирует то нужно эти подключения искать в файлах админки?

Comment: Вероятно гдето в настройках (база или файлы настроек), где указан домен. Вам нужно `http://` поменять на `https://`

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению движок **[Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/)** использует не относительные пути, а абсолютные. Это является серьёзно проблемой в случаях:

1. перенос сайта на другой домен.
2. изменение протокола http на https.
3. изменение-обновление самого движка, или плагинов.

Свою проблему решил так:

1. Выгрузил на локальный сервер
2. Скачал sql и сохранил локально
3. программой notepad++ найти в файлах / заменить, удалил все схемы со всех ссылок.
4. в .htaccess задал uri.scheme.

Мне помог разобраться [этот ресурс](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.